# how to sort 2 associative arrays with first array order with second array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have 2 associative arrays.

```
$a1 = array(
    'blue' =>
    array('id' => 2365,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'blue'),
    'black' =>
    array('id' => 478,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'black'),
    'green' =>
    array('id' => 698,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'green'),
    'red' =>
    array('id' => 169,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'red')
$a2= array(
    'green' =>
    array('id' => 452,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'green'),
    'black' =>
    array('id' => 124,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'black'),
    'red' =>
    array('id' => 124,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'red'),
    'blue' =>
    array('id' => 145,
          'level' => 1,
          'name' => 'blue')
);
```

I want to sort my second array in the first array key order. That means I want to sorry my array of blue, black, green, red.
My desired result like:

```
$a2= array(
       'blue' =>
        array('id' => 145,
              'level' => 1,
              'name' => 'blue'),
       'black' =>
        array('id' => 124,
              'level' => 1,
              'name' => 'black'),
       'green' =>
        array('id' => 452,
              'level' => 1,
              'name' => 'green'),
        'red' =>
        array('id' => 124,
              'level' => 1,
              'name' => 'red'),
    );
```

For this I am using the code :

```
uasort($a2, function($a, $b) use ($a1) { return array_search($a['name'], $a1) - array_search($b['name'], $a1); }
```

But I didn't get my desired result.
Also I tried with this:

```
uksort($a2, function($key1, $key2) use ($a1) {
        return (array_search($key1, $a1) - array_search($key2, $a1));
    });
```

Another method: But again, I didn't get my desired result.

```
$price = array(); 
foreach ($a2 as $key => $row) {
  $price[$key] = $row['name'];
} 
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $a1);
```

Comment: Check out `array_multisort()`, it might be able to do this.

Comment: I also tried with array_multisort() .$price = array();
    foreach ($a2 as $key => $row)
    {
        $price[$key] = $key;
    }
    array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $a1);

Answer (score 0):

I just use the following concept:

```
$arr2ordered = array() ;

foreach (array_keys($a1) as $key) {
    $arr2ordered[$key] = $a2[$key] ;
}
```

After that, I got my desired result.

Comment: did you answer your own question?